# How to customize WooCommerce price suffix under price amount with css?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress E-Commerce website and while I was working on the design, I couldn't do what I wanted to do. WC Has a option inside of "tax" setting which one called "Price prefix".

When i open it, it's write next of price amount but i want to locate it below. How can i do it ? i could not find it's code.

[image]

Comment: this should be pretty easy to do in CSS, something like `.woocommerce-price-suffix {  display: block; }` please post the markup of a product's price.

Comment: Really thanks i do not know how to forget it. Before, i tried to change his position like position : absolute and etc. Thank you so much